# Can silicon temperature sensor (e.g. KTY84)'s polarity be inferred if it's inaccesible - polarity band cannot be visually checked?

Tags: identification, thermistor, ptc

I have two electric motors at my disposal, both equipped with [KTY84-130](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/KTY84_SER.pdf) silicon temperature sensors (PTC thermistors).
The sensors themselves are buried deep within the innards of the motors and I don't want to meddle there if not absolutely required.

I always thought these type of sensors are just temperature-dependent resistors, so polarity does not matter. Indeed, when measured with a DMM, they show the same resistance (around 620 ohms at room temp) in both directions.

However, the Curtis controller manual warns about observing proper polarity:

[image: excerpt from Curtis controller manual]

Moreover, after some digging in the datasheet of the KTY84 it seems they are non-symmetrical, but only above 150°C:

[image: excerpt from KTY84 datasheet]

## Question

I'm looking for some minor tell-tale sign to infer the polarity (like how you can discern between the B-E and B-C junction of a NPN - the diode drop is slightly lower for the B-E). All I have is:

- the two motors with coloured wires sticking out of them¹
- two more sensors (as through-hole parts)
- DMM/bench PSU/etc. (normal lab equipment)

How (if it's possible) can I identify the polarity?

## One method (which I don't like)

I can pass current to self-heat the thermistors, but I'll have to cook them over 150°C for this method to work, and I'll very likely need to exceed the absolute maximum rating for current to achieve sufficient heating. I'll keep this as a last-resort method.

---

¹ <sub>and those wires don't help either; they are not even consistent between the two motors. I asked the guys who made the motors, they don't know how they installed them, they too were thinking the sensors don't have polarity.</sub>

Comment: Now that's a tricky one.

Comment: @anrieff Have you tried using the diode mode on your meter to check the polarity?

Comment: @VoltageSpike, it looks completely symmetrical. In diode test it shows "0.605" in both directions (I assume it tests with 1mA). When I pass 3.00V through it it consumes 4.94mA in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a manual for another (polarized KTY device) that gives a little more information about it:
https://carbonbrushsolution.com/wp-content/pdf_datablad/datablad-kty-84.eng.pdf
 On the first page is the most relevant information:
"Colour/Connection
• KTY 84 is a semi-conductor where one end is an
 anode (plus) and the other a cathode (minus). A wide
 range of colour combinations is available on the market.
 The sensor’s ring marking can be checked to ensure
 the wiring is correct. The ring is the cathode side. *It is
 therefore of the utmost importance to know what the
 wire colour codes are for the anode and cathode in
 those cases where the sensor is embedded.* **To verify
 the polarity by way of measurement requires heating
 of the sensor to see when the resistance follows the
 temperature curve as shown in the data sheet.**


 So, you have to heat the sensor in order to test its polarity.


 If you are able to see the sensor's wire colors, you might be able to get the polarity right, but this depends on the manufacturer and possibly custom-specified color-coding. I have found one below:
https://www.ephy-mess.de/fileadmin/Daten/Downloads/Produktkataloge_EN/EPHY-MESS_GmbH_Catalog_Semiconductor_thermistors.pdf
 on page 13 there is a color-code mentioned for a KTY84 sensor:
"Colour code¹
**(+) = yellow

(-) = green**
¹Colour code of EPHY-MESS KTY84-1xx sensors"

So, there you have it, you either have to heat the sensor up to test it with a multimeter, or you could check the color codes used by the manufacturer. Hopefully, this is the color-coding used in your case.

P.S.: Since they are non-symmetrical only above 150°C, the polarity might not matter if you only need it up to that temperature, as you must have figured that out already.

Comment: The datasheet suggests heating the sensor to see if it matches the posted resistance curve. However I can't really heat the entire motor to 150°C, I don't have an oven for that, and even if I had, it may be detrimental to the motor.

Comment: You can heat it by applying a current through it (slowly and carefully). You don't need to raise its temperature that high.

Comment: That's one option, but as stated, I don't like it. The datasheet specs the max current is 10mA. At 100°C the KTY part is 1kΩ, so 10V*10mA = 100mW. I may be unable to increase the temperature via self-heating without violating the 10mA absolute maximum rating.

Comment: Re "My thinking is if your PTC is showing the same resistance in both directions, then it is not a polarized type (not a silistor)" — the KTY84/130 datasheet clearly states that below 150°C the resistance curve is the same in both directions, for 1mA at least. Maybe the symmetry is broken earlier at higher currents, I may try that...

Comment: I have updated/edited my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the wire colours are not yellow/green on neither motor; nor the other Siemens standard colouring. One of the motors is rated to 120°C, so, as you say, determination there is not important. The other is up to 180°C, though.

Comment: What are the colors on both PTCs?

Comment: Grey/brown on one of them, black/brown on the other. These wires do not come with the sensors though, they've been added by the guys that made the motors, and they don't remember how they soldered them.

Comment: Ugh! Let's hope they at least did the soldering part right.

Answer (score 1):

You can also provide a current of -2 or -3 mA, the reverse effect will be visible at lower temperatures. In the datasheet I could not find anything about the safe operation conditions for the device but it seems not to be damaging. If you don't trust it, buy a separate device to do an experiment.